# Working with strong obfuscated Java

Tags: disassembly, decompilation, java, deobfuscation

I've got a jar file, that is strong obfuscated.

- When I tried to put it into decompilers such as bytecode-viewer and luyten I seen many lines of traps and Chinese letters.
- I tried to deobfuscate it using [java-debofuscator](https://github.com/java-deobfuscator/deobfuscator) but unfortunately, the deobfuscator crashes.

[download jar file](https://www.mediafire.com/file/yrwfhapn1aqc8km/file_to_deobfuscate.jar/file)

[image]
Can someone help me or give me advice on how I can deal with it?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

First off, have you tried [the Krakatau decompiler](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau)? Krakatau is designed specifically for working with obfuscated Java bytecode, although the decompiler doesn't support lambdas and isn't very user friendly.

That being said, renamed identifiers is not something any tool will able to help you with. You'll just have to reverse engineer it and change them to more meaningful names yourself.

If decompilation fails, you can also try the Krakatau disassembler. The advantage of disassembly is that it always works, no matter how heavily the bytecode has been obfuscated. It lets you see what's really in the bytecode without the risk of things getting messed up by decompilation. The downside is that it's generally a lot harder to read.

Comment: Yes, I tried to use Krakatau, but decompiling process removes all important classes (these with Chinese name).

Comment: No it doesn't. They'll just have different filenames than you might expect since Krakatau forces the output source to have ascii filenames in order to avoid shenanigans. Look closely at the files the decompiler outputs. They will be there, just with weird filenames.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a tool I created called [Threadtear](https://github.com/GraxCode/threadtear) to remove those senseless jumps. It is like java-deobfuscator, but with a GUI and support for newer obfuscator versions. Use Generic > Remove obvious flow obfuscation. You can also reobfuscate the class names / method names to get rid of annoying chinese letters.